# Getting Only one expression can be specified in the select list when the subquery is not introduced with EXISTS

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am getting this error and am unsure how to fix it. I am trying to decide if @type = one thing select everything from that temp table. There are 2 temp tables so there are 2 choices.
There is a third choice where they can select both tables, which i am unioning together.
The explanation for the error on stack overflow doesn't seem to fit, as I've used this before and it worked (the union part at least).
As a side note, i'd like to do an order by clause on the unioned part, but it wont let me. is there a way to do that?
Heres the part causing the error. the two temp tables work fine when run individually, but not through this select statement. I am using sql server 2005

```
Select
        Case 
            WHEN @type like 'Sent%' THEN
                (Select * from #Sent)
            WHEN @Type like 'Confirm%' THEN
                (Select * From #Confirmed)
            Else
                ( Select 
                    T.QT#
                    ,T.QTLine
                    ,T.DIVISION
                    ,T.Customer
                    ,T.CustomerAccount
                    ,T.Industry
                    ,T.Type
                    ,T.ProgramName
                    ,T.SalesGroup
                    ,T.Recipient
                    ,T.ItemGroup
                    ,T.OEM
                    ,T.CustomerClassification
                    ,T.Finish
                    ,T.Item
                    ,T.EAU
                    ,T.PriceUnit
                    ,T.Price
                    ,T.ExtValue
                    ,T.VMPercent
                    ,T.VM$
                    ,T.RFQRecdTime
                    ,T.SentTime
                    ,T.QuotationToSentTurnTime
                    ,T.RFQRecdDate
                    ,T.SentDate
                    ,T.ConfirmedDate
                    ,T.QuotetoOrderTurnTime
                    ,T.FiscalMonthSent
                    ,T.FiscalMonthConfirmed
                    ,T.Status
                FROM
                    (
                        Select
                            QT#
                            ,QTLine
                            ,DIVISION
                            ,Customer
                            ,CustomerAccount
                            ,Industry
                            ,[Type]
                            ,ProgramName
                            ,SalesGroup
                            ,Recipient
                            ,ItemGroup
                            ,[OEM]
                            ,CustomerClassification
                            ,Finish
                            ,Item
                            ,EAU
                            ,PriceUnit
                            ,Price
                            ,ExtValue
                            ,VMPercent
                            ,VM$
                            ,RFQRecdTime
                            ,SentTime
                            ,QuotationToSentTurnTime
                            ,RFQRecdDate
                            ,SentDate
                            ,ConfirmedDate
                            ,QuotetoOrderTurnTime
                            ,FiscalMonthSent
                            ,FiscalMonthConfirmed
                            ,[Status]
                        From
                            #Sent
                    UNION ALL
                        Select
                            QT#
                            ,QTLine
                            ,DIVISION
                            ,Customer
                            ,CustomerAccount
                            ,Industry
                            ,[Type]
                            ,ProgramName
                            ,SalesGroup
                            ,Recipient
                            ,ItemGroup
                            ,[OEM]
                            ,CustomerClassification
                            ,Finish
                            ,Item
                            ,EAU
                            ,PriceUnit
                            ,Price
                            ,ExtValue
                            ,VMPercent
                            ,VM$
                            ,RFQRecdTime
                            ,SentTime
                            ,QuotationToSentTurnTime
                            ,RFQRecdDate
                            ,SentDate
                            ,ConfirmedDate
                            ,QuotetoOrderTurnTime
                            ,FiscalMonthSent
                            ,FiscalMonthConfirmed
                            ,[Status]
                        From
                            #Confirmed
    ) T
    GROUP BY
                    T.QT#
                    ,T.QTLine
                    ,T.DIVISION
                    ,T.Customer
                    ,T.CustomerAccount
                    ,T.Industry
                    ,T.Type
                    ,T.ProgramName
                    ,T.SalesGroup
                    ,T.Recipient
                    ,T.ItemGroup
                    ,T.OEM
                    ,T.CustomerClassification
                    ,T.Finish
                    ,T.Item
                    ,T.EAU
                    ,T.PriceUnit
                    ,T.Price
                    ,T.ExtValue
                    ,T.VMPercent
                    ,T.VM$
                    ,T.RFQRecdTime
                    ,T.SentTime
                    ,T.QuotationToSentTurnTime
                    ,T.RFQRecdDate
                    ,T.SentDate
                    ,T.ConfirmedDate
                    ,T.QuotetoOrderTurnTime
                    ,T.FiscalMonthSent
                    ,T.FiscalMonthConfirmed
                    ,T.Status
```

Comment: So, let's get this clear, you are trying to put the result of a `SELECT *` in one column. Can you see why that's not allowed when that select returns more than one row?

Comment: But i cant even use an Exists or In when inside a case statement. An why is it only in one column. i guess i dont understand

Comment: the `CASE` expression needs to return **one** value per row, it can't return a whole `SELECT` that has more than one column and one row

Comment: So what way do you go to select a tables result?

Comment: I don't understand your question, sorry.

Comment: If i cant use a case statement to return a tables result based upon criteria, what can i do to get it?

Comment: Use an `IF`?, I'm not sure of what you want, and it isn't really related to the current question

Comment: oh, an if works ok for the first two. Is there a way to get an Order By For the unioned statement?

Comment: Really, as I said before, I don't know what it is that you want to do, it does seems like a different question

Comment: the if statements are allowing me to select the tables based on what criteria i want, as in the main question. The last part of the code above is a union, and i am wondering if i can use a group by clause in some way

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I replaced the case statement with If...else

```
    IF @Type like 'Sent%'

            (SELECT 
                        QT#
                        ,QTLine
                        ,DIVISION
                        ,Customer
                        ,CustomerAccount
                        ,Industry
                        ,[Type]
                        ,ProgramName
                        ,SalesGroup
                        ,Recipient
                        ,ItemGroup
                        ,[OEM]
                        ,CustomerClassification
                        ,Finish
                        ,Item
                        ,EAU
                        ,PriceUnit
                        ,Price
                        ,ExtValue
                        ,VMPercent
                        ,VM$
                        ,RFQRecdTime
                        ,SentTime
                        ,QuotationToSentTurnTime
                        ,RFQRecdDate
                        ,SentDate
                        ,ConfirmedDate
                        ,QuotetoOrderTurnTime
                        ,FiscalMonthSent
                        ,FiscalMonthConfirmed
                        ,[Status]
            FROM #Sent)

        IF @Type like 'Confirm%' 
            (SELECT 
                        QT#
                        ,QTLine
                        ,DIVISION
                        ,Customer
                        ,CustomerAccount
                        ,Industry
                        ,[Type]
                        ,ProgramName
                        ,SalesGroup
                        ,Recipient
                        ,ItemGroup
                        ,[OEM]
                        ,CustomerClassification
                        ,Finish
                        ,Item
                        ,EAU
                        ,PriceUnit
                        ,Price
                        ,ExtValue
                        ,VMPercent
                        ,VM$
                        ,RFQRecdTime
                        ,SentTime
                        ,QuotationToSentTurnTime
                        ,RFQRecdDate
                        ,SentDate
                        ,ConfirmedDate
                        ,QuotetoOrderTurnTime
                        ,FiscalMonthSent
                        ,FiscalMonthConfirmed
                        ,[Status] FROM #Confirmed)
        ELSE
            ( SELECT 
                T.QT#
                ,T.QTLine
                ,T.DIVISION
                ,T.Customer
                ,T.CustomerAccount
                ,T.Industry
                ,T.Type
                ,T.ProgramName
                ,T.SalesGroup
                ,T.Recipient
                ,T.ItemGroup
                ,T.OEM
                ,T.CustomerClassification
                ,T.Finish
                ,T.Item
                ,T.EAU
                ,T.PriceUnit
                ,T.Price
                ,T.ExtValue
                ,T.VMPercent
                ,T.VM$
                ,T.RFQRecdTime
                ,T.SentTime
                ,T.QuotationToSentTurnTime
                ,T.RFQRecdDate
                ,T.SentDate
                ,T.ConfirmedDate
                ,T.QuotetoOrderTurnTime
                ,CONVERT(VarChar,T.FiscalMonthSent) As FiscalMonthSent
                ,CONVERT(VARCHAR,T.FiscalMonthConfirmed) AS FiscalMonthConfirmed
                ,T.Status
            FROM
                (
                    SELECT
                        QT#
                        ,QTLine
                        ,DIVISION
                        ,Customer
                        ,CustomerAccount
                        ,Industry
                        ,[Type]
                        ,ProgramName
                        ,SalesGroup
                        ,Recipient
                        ,ItemGroup
                        ,[OEM]
                        ,CustomerClassification
                        ,Finish
                        ,Item
                        ,EAU
                        ,PriceUnit
                        ,Price
                        ,ExtValue
                        ,VMPercent
                        ,VM$
                        ,RFQRecdTime
                        ,SentTime
                        ,QuotationToSentTurnTime
                        ,RFQRecdDate
                        ,SentDate
                        ,ConfirmedDate
                        ,QuotetoOrderTurnTime
                        ,CONVERT(VarChar,FiscalMonthSent) AS FiscalMonthSent
                        ,CONVERT(VarChar,FiscalMonthConfirmed) AS FiscalMonthConfirmed
                        ,[Status]
                    FROM
                        #Sent
                UNION ALL
                    SELECT
                        QT#
                        ,QTLine
                        ,DIVISION
                        ,Customer
                        ,CustomerAccount
                        ,Industry
                        ,[Type]
                        ,ProgramName
                        ,SalesGroup
                        ,Recipient
                        ,ItemGroup
                        ,[OEM]
                        ,CustomerClassification
                        ,Finish
                        ,Item
                        ,EAU
                        ,PriceUnit
                        ,Price
                        ,ExtValue
                        ,VMPercent
                        ,VM$
                        ,RFQRecdTime
                        ,SentTime
                        ,QuotationToSentTurnTime
                        ,RFQRecdDate
                        ,SentDate
                        ,ConfirmedDate
                        ,QuotetoOrderTurnTime
                        ,CONVERT(VarChar,FiscalMonthSent) AS FiscalMonthSent
                        ,CONVERT(VarChar,FiscalMonthConfirmed) AS FiscalMonthConfirmed
                        ,[Status]
                    FROM
                        #Confirmed
) T
GROUP BY
                T.QT#
                ,T.QTLine
                ,T.DIVISION
                ,T.Customer
                ,T.CustomerAccount
                ,T.Industry
                ,T.Type
                ,T.ProgramName
                ,T.SalesGroup
                ,T.Recipient
                ,T.ItemGroup
                ,T.OEM
                ,T.CustomerClassification
                ,T.Finish
                ,T.Item
                ,T.EAU
                ,T.PriceUnit
                ,T.Price
                ,T.ExtValue
                ,T.VMPercent
                ,T.VM$
                ,T.RFQRecdTime
                ,T.SentTime
                ,T.QuotationToSentTurnTime
                ,T.RFQRecdDate
                ,T.SentDate
                ,T.ConfirmedDate
                ,T.QuotetoOrderTurnTime
                ,T.FiscalMonthSent
                ,T.FiscalMonthConfirmed
                ,T.Status
    )
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use a single union of your two SELECTs with corresponding conditions to satisfy all three cases.

Basically, you want to read from `#Sent` when the argument is `LIKE 'Sent%'` or when it is something else but *not* `LIKE 'Confirm%'`, and same for `#Confirmed`: the argument should be either `LIKE 'Confirm%'` or *not* `LIKE 'Sent%'`.

So, here's how your query would look like:

```
SELECT
    QT#,
    ...
FROM #Sent
WHERE @type     LIKE 'Sent%'
   OR @type NOT LIKE 'Confirm%'

UNION

SELECT
    QT#,
    ...
FROM #Confirmed
WHERE @type     LIKE 'Confirm%'
   OR @type NOT LIKE 'Sent%'
;
```

Note that the third value or pattern of `@type` is not supposed to be NULL. If it can be NULL and the NULL should match both tables, you'll need to modify the conditions slightly by replacing

```
... OR @type NOT LIKE ...
```

with something like

```
... OR ISNULL(@type, '') NOT LIKE ...
```

Please note also the absence of `GROUP BY` and the use of `UNION` instead of `UNION ALL`. In your query you are grouping the combined set by the same columns that you are pulling from each table, and the same columns are ultimately returned in the output. My understanding is that the method is supposed to eliminate duplicates that may happen across the two tables. But that is essentially re-invention of the wheel, because `UNION` does just that: it combines two sets *and* eliminates duplicates. So, your query gets simplified in that respect too, as shown.